# Segmentation Fault when I try accessing an array of strings

Tags: c, malloc

what I am trying to do is to load from a file a sequence of characters, and put them inside a dynamically declared array of strings. The loading process works fine, but whenever I try accessing one of these strings the program goes into Segmentation fault.
From the file I first read the number of strings that will compose the array (`prop_cmd_number`), then I create the with the right size.

Read file function:

```
//Global variables
unsigned char prop_interface;
unsigned int prop_interface_parameter;
float prop_supply_voltage;
unsigned int prop_cmd_number;
unsigned char **prop_cmd_parameters;

void read_prop_file(){
    fscanf(prop_config, "%c %d\n%f %d\n", &prop_interface, &prop_interface_parameter, 
        &prop_supply_voltage, &prop_cmd_number);

    prop_cmd_parameters = malloc(prop_cmd_number * sizeof(char *));

    unsigned int tmp = 0;
    for(i=0; i<prop_cmd_number; i++){
        prop_cmd_parameters[i] = malloc(200 * sizeof(char)); 
        fscanf(prop_config, "P%02d", &tmp);

        unsigned char xx, yy = 0;
        int tmp_len = 0;

        
        while(yy != '\n'){
            fscanf(prop_config, "%c", &yy);
            if(yy == '\n')
                break;

            fscanf(prop_config, "0x%2x", &xx);
            //printf("%2x ", xx);
            prop_cmd_parameters[i][tmp_len++] = xx;
            
        }
        //printf("\n");
        prop_cmd_parameters[i][tmp_len] = '\0';
        printf("P%d : %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n", i+1, prop_cmd_parameters[i][0], prop_cmd_parameters[i][1], prop_cmd_parameters[i][2],
            prop_cmd_parameters[i][3], prop_cmd_parameters[i][4], prop_cmd_parameters[i][5], prop_cmd_parameters[i][6]);
    }
    fclose(prop_config);
}
```

Example of prop_config.txt

```
I 0

12.0 2

P01 0x40 0x40

P02 0x41 0x40
```

If I try to access to `prop_cmd_parameters` outside the function it simply goes into SegFault.. why?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  The bug might be in the code outside this function that accesses the data, or in unrelated code causing memory corruption.

Comment: For instance `unsigned char xx; fscanf(prop_config, "0x%2x", &xx);` is wrong because `%x` expects a pointer to `unsigned int`, not `unsigned char`; you'll overwrite other memory.  There are several other instances where signedness is wrong.  Compiler warnings should tell you about all of these.